# How to scrape the text next to end tag in BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I scrape this html ?

```
<h3>
<span class="method">GET&nbsp;</span>
[/r/
<em class="placeholder">subreddit</em>
]/api/user_flair
<span class="oauth-scope-list"><a href="https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2"><span class="api-badge oauth-scope">flair</span></a>
</span>
</h3>
```

Is there any method to get text below span tag. I know that using `next` or `next_sibling` I can get next text. But is there any other work around for this something like `h3.span`

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: There are two span tags. What is the output that you want from this?

Comment: I want `GET [/r/sureddit]/api/use_flair flair`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can catch your `text`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<h3>
                    <span class="method">GET&nbsp;</span>
                    [/r/
                    <em class="placeholder">subreddit</em>
                    ]/api/user_flair
                    <span class="oauth-scope-list"><a href="https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2"><span class="api-badge oauth-scope">flair</span></a>
                    </span>
                    </h3>""")
api_badges = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'api-badge oauth-scope'})
api_badges_txt = [api_badge.text for api_badge in api_badges]
```

The output is

```
['flair']
```

If you use

```
add_space = soup.find('em').next_sibling.replace('\n', '').strip()
soup.find('h3').get_text(strip=True).replace(add_space, add_space + ' ')
```

you get `'GET[/r/subreddit]/api/user_flair flair'`

Comment: actually I want to get above response as shown in in above [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892545/how-to-scrape-the-text-next-to-end-tag-in-beautifulsoup4#comment92705018_52892545)

Comment: Yes thanks. Is there any way I can add space before flair ? Also one more question if you don't mind. Is there any way I can find h3 tags which contains GET text

Comment: Absolutely please see the edit. Also please accept answer if it solves the question :)